# .NET Event Best Practice - Expose via property or return in EventArgs

Tags: c#, events, class

I'm unsure about the best practice for event handling/class design.

I have a class that has a method `Discover()`. When the method completes it raises an event, `DiscoveryCompleted`. The `DiscoveryCompleted` event has `EventArgs`.

In the `Discover()` method a List of objects are created. Should these be returned when the `DiscoveryCompleted` event fires in the `EventArgs` (will still need to create a class that derives from `EventArgs`), or be set as a property (`ReadOnlyCollection`) on the class. I have a bool `Discovered` which is set when the `DiscoveryCompleted` fires, so this can be used to determine if data should be populated.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Essentially the data returned to the subscriber, will be changed at a later stage, by passing that into another method (in the same assembly, different class).
When that method completes it would also return the updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this ultimately boils down to the architecture / extensibility points you want to enable with your code.  Does a consumer of the `Discover` function always want to / need to interact with the `object`s that are discovered?  If so then they should be returned from the `Discover` method.  However, if calling `Discover` keeps those objects for use internally with other methods, and knowing which objects were discovered were optional (or you don't want to do something with them beyond the classes core functionality every time), then providing the information through an event is a good choice.

Comment: The Discover method is a long running method and should eventually be called asyncronously. It is very likely that the returned objects will be used and passed to another method and class for further processing.

Answer (score 3):

If the data is either transitive (where the value might change after the event has fired and you want subscribers to be able to view the data that pertains to that particular event) or not directly related to your component (the result of an async call that the component won't use itself later), then return it in the event args.

Otherwise, if it would make sense to expose the value as a property on the component (disregarding your event), then do that and don't worry about the `EventArgs`. If not, then include it in the args.

Answer (score 1):

I think most developers would return them in a class that inherits from EventArgs.  This way any method subscribing to your event would have the result right there in their event handler.

```
class EventArgsX : EventArgs {
        public IEnumerable<object> YourCollection { get; set; }
}

instance.SomeEvent += (s, args) => {
   foreach(object O in args.YourCollection){
      //do something
   }
}
```

A lot is left out, but I'm sure you get the point.

Comment: Even if the data is only retrievable via a property, it is still always available to the subscribing handler via the `object sender` argument (`s` in your example). This argument contains the object that sent the Event (i.e. the object with the data in question).

Comment: Yeah, true.  I guess it's just a matter of preference.  Attaching it to the args does seem to be the more common practice, but like you said you could do it either way.  Unless of course the data could change after the event, as @Adam Robinson mentioned, in which case it should be on the args

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the data in question. If it makes sense for the data to be part of the class, then there should be a property for it. If it doesn't make sense for the class to encapsulate the data, then create an EventArg class for it.

Think about how Control events are done. CheckBox.CheckChanged doesn't pass the Checked state because that makes sense as a property for the CheckBox class, but the KeyPress event passes KeyPressEventArgs because the key that was pressed has nothing to do with the CheckBox itself.